# API Automation Testing using Katalon Studio- automate the process of OAuth 2.0 authorization token generation

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, automated-tests, authorization, katalon-studio

I have started using Katalon-Studio for API Automation testing.
I want to automate the process of OAuth 2.0 authorization token/barear token generation and then update it to HTTP Header instead of filling the data under authorization tab manually,Is there any way to automate this step? 
It would be helpful if someone can help me in this.

Thank You!

Comment: got solution for this..